# How to make the system speak a title or body text of a notification with Swift

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I've been looking for how to make the system speaks alertTitle or alertBody of a notification when the notification appears in the background with Swift but until now I don't find any solution.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertTitle = "Wake up"
notification.alertBody = "What's your agenda today?"
notification.fireDate = time
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

So how would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way** to achieve this programatically. You can not put anything into your `UILocalNotification` object to achieve this.

iOS supports VoiceOver, and you can set it up so it reads **all** your incoming notifications. To do this, go to the **Settings** --> **Accessiblity** --> Turn on **VoiceOver** --> **Verbosity** --> Turn on **Always Speak Notifications**.

This is a system wide setting that the user will have to enable however. It is valid for all applications, and not just yours.